# Unity, reload scene completely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I have two scenes: Menu and Game where the maze is randomly generated every launch.

After the Player dies in the maze I load the scene Menu where the Player can press button Start which should generate a new maze but instead it just loads the old scene with maze where Player died earlier.

I want to generate the new maze every time after pressing Start button.
Also, when I play the scene with maze separately everything works correctly
For scene loading I use:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
```

with indexes defined in Build settings.

If any additional code is needed just ask me and I will add it.

UPDATE
I have a class MazeGenerator where I have delegate and event:

```
public delegate void MazeReadyAction();
public static event MazeReadyAction OnMazeReady;
```

Event triggers when the maze is generated and is used in MazeDirecives class to set the Enemies and Coins when the maze is ready.
So that I MazeDirectives have lines:

```
void Awake()
{
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;    
}

void StartDirectives()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < mazeCoinPositions.Count; i++)
    {
        MazeCoin mazeCoin = Instantiate(mazeCoinPrefab, mazeCoinPositions[i], 
            Quaternion.identity) as MazeCoin;
            mazeCoin.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
}
```

Error:
`MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'MazeDirectives' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it`   pups up on:

```
mazeCoin.transform.SetParent(transform);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: SceneManager.LoadScene() should work. How are you storing the data for the maze and the player? If you're using scriptable objects you need to remember that changes made in them during gameplay stick around.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave I don't save any data. The point is to create a new data randomly everytime the scene loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
public static event MazeReadyAction OnMazeReady;
```

is `static` it keeps being there also if there woud be an instance of that class being destroyed.

So that after

```
MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;
```

that listener keeps being called though the `MazeDirectives` object you registered as listener is getting destroyed because of `SceneManager.Load`. So the next time when `OnMazeReady` is called you have actually two listeners registered: The one from the first scene which now is destroyed, and the one from the "new" scene.

You should either remove the old listener

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady -= StartDirectives;
}
```

or not even "stack" them but only asign exactly one listener

```
private void Awake()
{
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady = StartDirectives;
}
```

this does ofcourse only apply if there is no other listener in your scene.

Anyway you should reset it just to be sure

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady = null;
}
```

---

General Note: It is always save to call

```
MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady -= StartDirectives;
```

even if the listener wasn't added before. So doing

```
private void Awake()
{
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady -= StartDirectives;
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;
}
```

also makes sure that the listener can allways be added only exactly once.

Comment: I would argue that it can be confusing to have multiple static elements in multiple classes for a reader. Thus I propose what appears to me as better practize in general:
Make the event non-static, and move the adding and removing of listeners in either onenable and ondisable, or awake and ondestroy, depending on the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat brute force, but should do the trick.  This routine would be called from the main menu scene before you load the maze scene.

```
int scenes = SceneManager.sceneCount;
if (scenes > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < scenes; i++)
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).name == "Name of Maze Scene")
        {
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).name);
        }
    }
}
```